# Cannot position div at the center of another div

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why the div with id 'text' gets a height and width of 100% automatically.
I want it to center like the div with id 'logo' and give it a padding on the top and bottom of 77px.

Please help.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper-1">
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="logo">
    Logo
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper-2">
<div class="divider"></div>
<div id="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam  nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #131316;
}

.divider{
width: 1px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
margin: auto;
z-index: 1;
}

#wrapper-1{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#logo{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 177px;
height: 177px;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
color: #131316;
z-index: 2;
}

#wrapper-2{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#text{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is the fiddle - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ybn950kv/)

Comment: You haven't set a height and width for #text whereas you have for #logo?

Comment: Wrapper-2 has 100%  width and height. Also you have not assigned any values for text div. Override the values for text div as well and you should be good. One suggestion, if both div will have same size, create another class and share it in both div. This will give you more flexibility and in future if you wanna update values, you will have to update it at one place only

Comment: Is it necessary to set a height and width? What if I just give it a padding on all sides?

Comment: give width and height for #text div as you specified for logo

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ybn950kv/5/) representing use of **slide** class.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ybn950kv/1/)

css

```
#text{                        //its a div so display block by default, thus width 100% by default.
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    width:177px;
    height:177px;            //you need to give width and height here, as to explicitly absolute positioned it with top, left, right, bottom 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update your #text class as per below:

```
#text {
position: absolute;
width: 177px;
height: 177px;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255)
}
```